# How to parse nested JSON in python

Tags: python, json, content-type

I'm struggling to access some values in this nested json in python.

How can I access this ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'] ? I did search a lot to find a simple python snippet, but no luck. Thanks in advance!

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventName": "xxxxxxx",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "8CXXXXXXXXXXHRQX",
        "x-amz-id-2": "doZ3+gxxxxxxx"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "X-Event",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "bucket-name",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "xxxxxxx"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "object.png",
          "sequencer": "0060XXXXXXX75X"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [`json.loads`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_json_parse.asp)

Comment: @cosmos-1905-14 Is this a file or is it a JSON string?

Comment: @TheSupreme It's a string

Comment: Actually, I made a library for this a little while ago: [QueryTree](https://pypi.org/project/querytree/). It makes writing to deeply nested structures and converting them between formats. But if you are just trying to read that value, you already did it. The snipet you gave will work. Just parse the json first with the built-in json library

Comment: @cosmos-1905-14 I'm not sure exactly what you mean by nested but both the links I gave can absolutely handle the JSON structure in your question

Comment: @QuinnFreedman, thanks. the json is kept in msg variable. I can't navigate in my json to read only one value due to the nested structure. Isn't there an easy way to do so? :( Can I import your QueryTree in AWS Lambda?

Comment: @cosmos-1905-14 I don't know what to tell you other than yes you can. You will need to parse the JSON from a string into a nested python dictionary. That's what json.loads does. Then the code you gave `['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']` will give you the value you want. Have you tried it? are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a string, use the `json.loads` method from the inbuilt JSON library.

```
import json

json_string = # your json string
parsed_string = json.loads(json_string)
print(parsed_string) # it will be a python dict
print(parsed_string['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']) # prints the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your example? If you're loading the json from elsewhere, you'd need to convert it to this native dictionary object using the `json` library (as mentioned by others, `json.loads(data)`)

```
kv = {
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventName": "xxxxxxx",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "8CXXXXXXXXXXHRQX",
        "x-amz-id-2": "doZ3+gxxxxxxx"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "X-Event",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "bucket-name",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "xxxxxxx"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "object.png",
          "sequencer": "0060XXXXXXX75X"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

print("RESULT:",kv['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'])

RESULT: bucket-name
```